# How to replace a multiple pattern in a column name with corresponding multiple patterns in an R data.frame?

Tags: r

I have a data.frame `DataSample` as shown below :

```
   Area Category.x TopSales Category.y BottomSales
1  East    Seafood 83220.19  Beverages     2135.17
2 North  Beverages 84324.99 Condiments     2658.95
3 South  Beverages 79202.89    Seafood      400.00
4  West  Beverages 70448.24 Condiments     1563.60
```

I wish to replace `Category.x` with `Category_Top` and `Category.y` with `Category_Bottom`, so I tried the following steps :

```
ColNameOld<-names(DataSample)

ColNameNew_1<-sub('.x','_Top',ColNameOld)

ColNameNew_2<-sub('.y','_Bottom',ColNameNew_1)

names(DataSample)<-ColNameNew_2
```

And hence I got the required result, which is shown below.

```
   Area Category_Top TopSales Category_Bottom BottomSales
1  East    Seafood   83220.19    Beverages      2135.17
2 North  Beverages   84324.99    Condiments     2658.95
3 South  Beverages   79202.89    Seafood        400.00
4  West  Beverages   70448.24    Condiments     1563.60
```

But my question is, how can I do it in a single step, where I pass a pattern of strings to be replaced and respective matching patterns, in separate vectors and use `sub()` or `gsub()` to replace them?

My patterns are always ".x" and ".y" and to be replaced by "_Top" and "_Bottom"

---

data sample:

```
structure(list(Area = c("East", "North", "South", "West"), Category.x = c("Seafood", 
"Beverages", "Beverages", "Beverages"), TopSales = c(83220.19, 
84324.99, 79202.89, 70448.24), Category.y = c("Beverages", "Condiments", 
"Seafood", "Condiments"), BottomSales = c(2135.17, 2658.95, 400, 
1563.6)), .Names = c("Area", "Category.x", "TopSales", "Category.y", 
"BottomSales"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use

```
library(gsubfn)
colnames(DataSample) <- gsubfn("(\\.(x|y))$", list(`.x`="_Top", 
                   `.y`= "_Bottom"), colnames(DataSample))
colnames(DataSample)
#[1] "Area"            "Category_Top"    "TopSales"        "Category_Bottom"
#[5] "BottomSales"
```

Or another option is `mgsub`

```
library(qdap)
mgsub(c('\\.x$', '\\.y$'), c('_Top', '_Bottom'), 
                      colnames(DataSample), fixed=FALSE)
#[1] "Area"            "Category_Top"    "TopSales"        "Category_Bottom"
#[5] "BottomSales"
```

#### Update

If there is a `list` of 'data.frames'

```
 lst <- list(DataSample, DataSample)
 lapply(lst, function(x) {colnames(x) <- gsubfn("(\\.(x|y))$",
       list(`.x`="_Top", `.y`= "_Bottom"),  colnames(x))
  x })
```

Comment: And why am I getting this `Error: '\.' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\."` when I try doing this? `paste0('colnames(',AllDataTables[i],')<-','gsubfn("\\.x|\\.y", list(`.x`="_Top",`.y`= "_Bottom"), colnames(',AllDataTables[i],
                       '))')`

Comment: @sunitprasad1 You cant assign `paste0('colnames(', ...)` directly.  Also, your code is confusing with `[i]` etc.  May be you are referring to something in a loop.

Comment: Yes, a group of data.frames which have .x and .y and to be replaced with Top and Bottom and I'm trying to take them in a loop.

Comment: @sunitprasad1 Updated the post to include the case where you have a list of dataframes

Comment: Well, I have all the data.frame names, `AllDataTables` as `c("DataSample1","DataSample2","DataSample3","DataSample4",)`. So, executed them one by one in a loop (not that violently, of course) by and then the `lapply()` - to finally get a list of tables whose column names are corrected!! But there is a problem here.. I have looked around for it but coudn't get any solution - How do I get the data.frames back and rename them to `DataSample1_new`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83183/discussion-between-sunitprasad1-and-akrun).

Comment: @sunitprasad1 I would keep the data.frames in the list as `lst` instead of creating new dataframe objects in the global environment.  It is easy to work in a list and almost all the processes can be done within the list itself